# Select one column multiple time

Tags: database, select

I want to select one column two time from a table.
E.g
( Select rent as rent1, rent as rent2 From Expense)
But I don't know how I can Select this column multiple time as each has its own Where Clause.
Means I want to select One Column two time On two different condition.

Comment: sorry to say this .. **but this makes no sense**....and i guess..this is not related to jquery at all..  post your related codes too..

Comment: If you are not actively manipulating a column or putting it in a condition, it makes absolutely no sense to select the same column (value) twice.

Comment: I am Using it In Crystal Reports And There are two different Column For Different Condition In Data Base This Information in single column So I Have to Select Two Column In Query .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a union

```
select test, 'rent1' from tableA where condA
union
select test, 'rent2' from tableA where condB
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to have both values in one result line (can't think of a reason why you would want this, but anyway...) you could use something like a self-join:

```
select a.rent as rent1, b.rent as rent2
from Expense a,
     Expense b
where a.condition
and b.condition
and a/b-join-condition
```